# Kendo MVC fire Create method on Update call

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo UI Grid with MVC 4 and it works great with only one exception.

If I add a row in the grid, and after that update a row, It end up adding a row rather than updating it.

What I can tell is that if I press add, the program enters the *Create* method in my MVC Controller, if I press Update on a row **after** the add I enter the *Create* method yet again.

This, However, does not seem to be the case if I just press the update button in the grid directly after start up. I am doing all this with Ajax calls so it has something to do with the page not updating between calls. Everything works great if I just do one command then refresh the page. Also I am using Entity Framework as ORM.

**This is my razor-view:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Internal.License.Management.Web.UI.Models.PriceListViewModel>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Price List";
}

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Internal.License.Management.Web.UI.Models.PriceListViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Code).Width(180);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Interval).Width(180);
        columns.Bound(p => p.PricePerUnit).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Currency).Width(120);
        columns.Command(commands =>
            {
                commands.Edit();
                commands.Destroy();
            }).Width(172);
    })
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource =>
    dataSource.Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
    .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "PriceList"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "PriceList"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "PriceList"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "PriceList"))
  ))
```

**This is my controller:**

```
public class PriceListController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        return View("PriceList");
    }

    public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var model = new DataAdapter().GetAllOptionTemplates();
        var result = model.ToDataSourceResult(request);

        return Json(result);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,  
                           PriceListViewModel model)
    {
        if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           new DataAdapter().SaveToDatabase(model);
        }

        return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,   
                           PriceListViewModel model)
    {
        if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           new DataAdapter().UpdateToDatabase(model);
        }

        return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
    } 
}
```

**This is my view model**

```
public class PriceListViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Option Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Interval { get; set; }
    public decimal PricePerUnit { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I remember having this issue once before but I can't find how I fixed it.

After you save the model to the database, make sure it has it's ID before you return it from the method.  (Debug and watch the `model` object).  If it doesn't, you can try something like this:

```
model.Id = saveditem.Id;
return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
```

Comment: I had the same problem as OP, and this fixed it. Seems like telerik needs the Id to know the item is not new anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the reason for this problem but I wrote a work-around.

I changed the KendoUI code part:

```
.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
```

to:

```
.Events(events => 
            { 
               events.Error("error_handler");
               events.RequestEnd("force_update");
            })
```

And then added a javascript to the page where I showed the grid.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function force_update(e) {
        if (e.type === "create") {
            location.reload();
        }
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead using location.reload() you can write e.sender.read();

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in an existing conflict in the grid because I didn't empty the datasource properly

Make sure to empty the datasource like that:

$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data([ ]);

Answer (score -1):

You can put a check based on `record.Id`. If it exists then update, if not then create new record.

Answer (score -1):

I also ran into this problem. The fact is that your grid does not get the ID of your records in the **Read** method, so it calls to Create and not Update